# What is the length in bytes of AesCryptoServiceProvider GenerateIV()?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric, initialization-vector

```
AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider()
var iv = aesAlg.GenerateIV();
```

Do you know what the length of iv? Is it fixed with byte[16]?

Another question is: what is the length requirement of initialization vector of AesCryptoServiceProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iv for AES is the same as the block size which is 128-bits/16-bytes.

AES has one fixed block size, and three key sizes: 128-bits, 192-bits and 256-bits.

Comment: If it is fixed to 16 bytes, will help me a lot. Thanks.